# マクロVBAで「BASIC ランタイムエラー」が出てきます。何が問題でしょうか？

Tags: vba

マクロ初心者です。
現在マクロの勉強をしてるのですが、以下のコードを実行しようとしたときに
「BASIC ランタイムエラー　Sub または Function プロシージャーの未定義」
とエラーが出てきて処理ができません。
何が問題なのでしょうか？

**■環境**
　OpenOffice

**■実行したマクロ**

```
Sub Module1 ()

Dim a As String
a = Cells(3, 2).Value
MsgBox (a)

End Sub
```

**■エラー文**
　BASIC ランタイムエラー　
　Sub または Function プロシージャーの未定義

**■確認した事項**
　・[ツール]>[オプション]>[読み込みと保存]>[VBA属性]>[実行可能コード]にチェック
　・[ツール]>[オプション]>[Java]>[Javaランタイム環境を使用]にチェック
　・マクロの配置を「マイマクロ」下から「{ファイル名}」下に変更
　・ファイルをxlsmファイルとして保存してから実行する
　
**■補足**
　「a = "Hello World"」のようにaを定義すると正常に実行され、
　メッセージボックスが表示されました。
　「Range」「Cells」のようなシートに働きかける関数を使用した途端に
　うまく動かなくなったので、何かしら環境上の問題ではないかと考えています。

以上が現在発生している問題です。
以前に同様の問題を経験したことのある方、解決方法のわかる方、
いらっしゃいましたらお答えいただきたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: VBAとOpenOffice.org BASICは別物(Cells(3, 2)のようにシートのセルにアクセスできない：エラーメッセージはCellsという手続きがないことを言っている)だと思います。

Comment: BLUEPIXY さん、ありがとうございます！OpenOfficeBasicとvbaは別物なんですね。OpenOfficeBasicを調べて試してみることにします。

Answer (score 1):

VBAについては詳しく知らないのですが、OpenOfficeを使っているということで、その観点から見ると

あなたが開発している言語はOpenOfficeのVBAと似た別のものらしいです。

「OpenOffice Basic」というものらしい。

もしかしたら、その環境では実行できないのかもしれません。